# Unsafe Edge Detection still slow

Tags: c#, wpf, image-processing

I'm trying to implement an Image Edge Detection into a WPF program.
I already have it working, but the converting of the image is quite slow.
The code is not using the slow GetPixel and SetPixel functions. But instead I'm looping through the image in some unsafe code so that I can directly access the value's using a pointer.
Before starting the Edge detection I'm also converting the image to a greyscale image to improve the edge detection speed.

But still it takes the program around 1600ms to convert an image with a size of 1920x1440 pixels, which I think could be much faster.

This is the original image:
[image: Original Image]

Which is converted to this (Snapshot of the application):
[image]

This is how I'm converting the image, I'm wondering what I can do to get to some other speed improvements?

Loading the image and create a Greyscale WriteableBitmap:

```
    private void imageData_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (imageData.Source != null)
        {
            BitmapSource BitmapSrc = new FormatConvertedBitmap(imageData.Source as BitmapSource, PixelFormats.Gray8 /* Convert to greyscale image */, null, 0);
            writeableOriginalBitmap = new WriteableBitmap(BitmapSrc);
            writeableBitmap = writeableOriginalBitmap.Clone();
            imageData.Source = writeableBitmap;
            EdgeDetection();
        }
    }
```

Converting the Image:

```
    private const int TOLERANCE = 20;

    private void EdgeDetection()
    {
        DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now;   //Save starting time
        writeableOriginalBitmap.Lock();
        writeableBitmap.Lock();
        unsafe
        {
            byte* pBuffer         = (byte*)writeableBitmap.BackBuffer.ToPointer();
            byte* pOriginalBuffer = (byte*)writeableOriginalBitmap.BackBuffer.ToPointer();

            for (int row = 0; row < writeableOriginalBitmap.PixelHeight; row++)
            {
                for (int column = 0; column < writeableOriginalBitmap.PixelWidth; column++)
                {
                    byte edgeColor = getEdgeColor(column, row, pOriginalBuffer); //Get pixel color based on edge value
                    pBuffer[column + (row * writeableBitmap.BackBufferStride)] = (byte)(255 - edgeColor);
                }
            }
        }

        //Refresh image
        writeableBitmap.AddDirtyRect(new Int32Rect(0, 0, writeableBitmap.PixelWidth, writeableBitmap.PixelHeight));
        writeableBitmap.Unlock();
        writeableOriginalBitmap.Unlock();

        //Calculate converting time
        TimeSpan diff = DateTime.Now - startTime;
        Debug.WriteLine("Loading Time: " + (int)diff.TotalMilliseconds);
    }

    private unsafe byte getEdgeColor(int xPos, int yPos, byte* pOriginalBuffer)
    {
        byte Color;
        byte maxColor = 0;
        byte minColor = 255;
        int difference;

        //Calculate max and min value of surrounding pixels
        for (int y = yPos - 1; y <= yPos + 1; y++)
        {
            for (int x = xPos - 1; x <= xPos + 1; x++)
            {
                if (x >= 0 && x < writeableOriginalBitmap.PixelWidth && y >= 0 && y < writeableOriginalBitmap.PixelHeight)
                {
                    Color = pOriginalBuffer[x + (y * writeableOriginalBitmap.BackBufferStride)];
                    if (Color > maxColor)            //If current pixel has higher value as previous max pixel
                        maxColor = Color;            //Save current pixel value as max
                    if (Color < minColor)            //If current pixel has lower value as previous min pixel
                        minColor = Color;            //Save current pixel value as min
                }
            }
        }

        //Difference of minimum and maximum pixel with tollerance
        difference = maxColor - minColor - TOLERANCE;
        if (difference < 0)
            difference = 0;

        return (byte)difference;
    }
```

Console Output:

```
Loading Time: 1599
```

Comment: I'd use [StopWatch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch?view=netframework-4.7.2) to get more accurate measurements - but that doesn't solve your issue.

Comment: Have you tried to run that code with simple byte arrays instead of WriteableBitmaps? Use BitmapSource.CopyPixels once to get a byte array from a BitmapSource, and BitmapSource.Create to convert back to a BitmapSource.

Comment: @Clemens I see you just posted an Answer, I didn't try a simple bite array. So started implementing it. This just gave me a huge time improvement and finished converting in just 343ms. Thanks for the useful tip. Let me now watch your answer to see if I can improve my code.

Comment: Not as significant, but accessing unchanged variables over and over is 5% of the performance, according to VS profiler: writeableBitmap.BackBufferStride and writeableOriginalBitmap.PixelHeight, writeableOriginalBitmap.PixelWidth.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following code runs your algorithm on a byte array instead of the BackBuffer of a WriteableBitmap. It completes in less than 300 ms with a 1900x1200 image on my PC.

```
private static BitmapSource EdgeDetection(BitmapSource source)
{
    var stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    var bitmap = new FormatConvertedBitmap(source, PixelFormats.Gray8, null, 0);
    var width = bitmap.PixelWidth;
    var height = bitmap.PixelHeight;
    var originalBuffer = new byte[width * height];
    var buffer = new byte[width * height];

    bitmap.CopyPixels(originalBuffer, width, 0);

    for (var y = 0; y < height; y++)
    {
        for (var x = 0; x < width; x++)
        {
            byte edgeColor = GetEdgeColor(originalBuffer, width, height, x, y);
            buffer[width * y + x] = (byte)(255 - edgeColor);
        }
    }

    Debug.WriteLine(stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);

    return BitmapSource.Create(
        width, height, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Gray8, null, buffer, width);
}

private static byte GetEdgeColor(byte[] buffer, int width, int height, int x, int y)
{
    const int tolerance = 20;
    byte minColor = 255;
    byte maxColor = 0;
    var xStart = Math.Max(0, x - 1);
    var xEnd = Math.Min(width - 1, x + 1);
    var yStart = Math.Max(0, y - 1);
    var yEnd = Math.Min(height - 1, y + 1);

    for (var j = yStart; j <= yEnd; j++)
    {
        for (var i = xStart; i <= xEnd; i++)
        {
            var color = buffer[width * j + i];
            minColor = Math.Min(minColor, color);
            maxColor = Math.Max(maxColor, color);
        }
    }

    return (byte)Math.Max(0, maxColor - minColor - tolerance);
}
```

Comment: Just like my comment on the question, this recomputes values in a for ending condition that do not change; in this case however, Math.Min(height, y + 2); (and for width) account for 20% of the total performance.

Comment: Also, there is no need to declare the color byte outside the inner loop. The performance is exactly the same with it defined just before usage, as in the original question.